# The file “Pods.xcconfig” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file

Tags: ios, git, cocoapods

How to solve this issue. I have downloaded the iOS project from the Git repo and when I try to build, it gives an error:

```
Check dependencies
The file “Pods.xcconfig” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file. (/Users/YoGesh/Desktop/Xy-3/Pods/Pods.xcconfig)
PhaseScriptExecution Check\ Pods\ Manifest.lock /Users/YoGesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Xy-bmwkojrwthnvzdfxthnxeqgesekm/Build/Intermediates/Xy.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Xy.build/Script-C0451AB63D7F4B73830000BA.sh
    cd /Users/YoGesh/Desktop/Xy-3
    /bin/sh -c /Users/YoGesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Xy-bmwkojrwthnvzdfxthnxeqgesekm/Build/Intermediates/Xy.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Xy.build/Script-C0451AB63D7F4B73830000BA.sh

diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.
```

Comment: would https://github.com/HipByte/motion-cocoapods/issues/68#issuecomment-25826735 help?

Comment: Try to run `pod install` in you project directory.

Comment: @dasdom when I try to install pod gives me error like - ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.



Please make sure you have the correct access rights

and the repository exists.

Answer (score 30):

I found a good hint [inside the issues](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2627) of `CocoaPods` on `GitHub`, try this:

1. Close your project (better close Xcode completely)
2. Open the Terminal inside your project and execute `pod install`
3. Open your project again. If there are still errors clean your project ( <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> ), after this the errors should be gone.

Comment: Thanks, Alexander the Great!

Comment: Head Shot...you the champ

Comment: Navigating to the project directory then running `pod install` fixes the issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 26):

Restarting `Xcode` helped me. `Pod update` and `install` didn't help.

Answer (score 6):

Go to your project directory from the terminal

run "pod update"

Answer (score 4):

Hey i had this same problem, I was getting the following error when running pod update however i didn’t realise the update wasn’t working.

$ pod update

Analyzing dependencies
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/pathname.rb:422:in `open': No such file or directory

It was because I forgot to run "pod setup" after installing cocoapods.
I ran pod setup from the terminal, followed it up with pod update (or pod install) and everything went to plan.

Answer (score 3):

Closing Xcode, pod update and pod install didn't help me.
I just ran the install cocoapods command again:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

If you see error:

> You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory

Use next command:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be using the Xcode default project file. After installing the framework through pod, you must use the generated xcworkspace in the project folder.

Example : SampleProject.xcworkspace.

Comment: Please try removing all pods, delete all pod config files and re-install again. Also check whether the pods are in correct format..

Answer (score 1):

For those who want to solve this issue and tried to remove the cocoa pods from the project:
1. Open the project, on the left side there must be a folder named Pods
2. Delete the folder and the problem will be solved
!!! Do not do this if you need cocoa pods

Answer (score 0):

I've experience a similar situation, for me, it's an error stop all the pods to be updated when I ran pod update.

Try to resolve the error and run pod update again, clean your project then try to build again.

Comment: Clean failed for me.

Answer (score 0):

I Tried `pod update` command in terminal for the project, it did not fix the issue.

then I Tried `pod install` command for the same project, it installed all the pod dependencies and the project got indexed and all those type of issues got fixed.