# Getting errors when adding CocoaPods to an existing project

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

My project,'Shag iBeacon' contains frameworks:

```
Bolts.framework,
Parse.framework,
AudioToolbox.framework,
CFNetwork.framework,
MobileCoreServices.framework,
QuartzCor‌​e.framework,
Security.framework
StoreKit.framework,
SystemConfiguratinon.framework,
​Accounts.framework,
Social.framework,
AdSupport.framework,
CoreLocation.framework,
Co‌​reBluetooth.framework,
Foundation.framework,
CoreGraphics.framework and
UIKit.framework.
```

I added CocoaPods to this existing Project and added the parse library to project using the statement: pod 'Parse'.I opened Shag iBeacon.xcworkspace and Icompiled the project But Iam getting an error as

```
The file “Pods-Shag iBeacon-Bolts-Private.xcconfig” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.
```

(I have attatched 2  screen shots of my projet navigator)

Could someone explain me how to solve this? Thanks in advance...[image][image]

Comment: Have you run `pod install`? Can we see the pod file?

Comment: Yes,run the pod install already...

Comment: POD FILE - # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '7.0'

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
inhibit_all_warnings!
target 'Shag iBeacon' do

pod 'Parse'


end

target 'Shag iBeaconTests' do

end

Comment: check these references [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589320/target-integrity-the-file-pods-ios-xcconfig-couldnt-be-opened-because-its-p)[link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24569183/the-file-pods-xcconfig-couldn-t-be-opened-because-there-is-no-such-file)

Answer (score 0):

My experience is on an Ionic project (therefore it may be different from yours a bit). I installed the lasted version and it appears ios projects now have some unique requirements. Googling around led me to upgrade cocoapods first then switch to an iOS platform directory (the one that has the project definition files) and run pod install.

I don't know who you'd do on XCode but from the terminal if you just run *pod install* (after making sure you have the latest cocoapods installed i.e *gem install cocoapods*) you should be fine.